Visa requirement for Cairo International Airport transit
I am travelling Mumbai - Cairo - London Heathrow on EgyptAir with a transit time of 3.30 hours at Cairo International airport. I am an Indian citizen and will have UK student visa at the time of travel. Do I need any transit visa for Cairo?

I suppose the two flights are on the same ticket?

@jcaron - Yes, they have the same PNR (booking reference). However, they are not booked through EgyptAir, rather a third party.

As long as they are on the same PNR it should be fine. Can you log into EgyptAir's "My booking" and see both flights?

Yes I can. I guess that means both flights are on the same ticket?

Yes, you’re all good.

Provided the two flights are on the same ticket, then Timatic says (via Emirates):

Visa
Visa required.
TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
Passengers transiting through Alexandria (HBE) with a boarding pass for a flight to a third country within 12 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.
Passengers with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 24 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination. Exception: This TWOV facility does not apply when transiting through Alexandria (HBE).

While this is a bit convoluted, in your case (transit via Cairo) the rule is:

Passengers with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 24 hours [don't need a visa for transit]. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.

So no, you don't need any kind of visa for Egypt.
The response would be quite different if the two flights were on separate tickets.

+1, but that's some seriously confusing phrasing. I think it's trying to say that visa free transits are max 12 hours at HBE only, and max 24 hours at all other international Egyptian airports including CAI?

@lambshaanxy that’s my understanding.
